# Some characters not being displayed properly when CSV opened in Excel

Tags: php, excel, csv, encoding, character-encoding

I know some people will think that this is duplicate question, but I tried all solutions provided on stackoverflow.

My problem is, I am not able to show some characters in CSV when opening in excel, however `notepad++` is showing it correctly.

Notepad++ output:

[image]

Excel output:

[image]

I know some guys will suggest me to show some headers & so, but I am just saving this CSV to server. User will download it using FTP when required.

Comment: Perhaps the Excel's encoding is terribly wrong? Also, where are you saving the CSV file from? If notepad++ opens it correctly the **file's encoding should be correct**, maybe it's just excel which is not interpreting it correctly. Maybe this can be helpful: http://superuser.com/questions/280603/how-to-set-character-encoding-when-opening-excel

Comment: @briosheje This is fine but I can't ask an user to do so. He would be interested to just open the file. Any programming way to fix this, please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you need a programming way to do this then the best way is to add a BOM character at the very beginning of your CSV file. Recent versions of Excel (Excel 2007 SP3 or more) do interpret this BOM character as an indicator that the rest of the file is in UTF-8 and load it correctly.

Here is the PHP code for that:

```
// generate $csv_content as usual
// fopen the file you want to write to in $csv
$BOM = "\xEF\xBB\xBF";
fwrite($csv, $BOM . $csv_content);
fclose($csv);
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because the character encoding for your file is UTF-8. Notepad++ correctly detects it, but Excel does not have character encoding detection and assumes everything is in the local Windows encoding.

Follow the steps outlined below to use Microsoft Excel 2007 to open a .csv file that uses UTF-8 character encoding:

- Open Microsoft Excel 2007.
- Click on the Data menu bar option.
- Click on the From Text icon.
- Navigate to the location of the file that you want to import.  Click on the filename and then click on the Import button.  The Text Import Wizard - Step 1 or 3 window will now appear on the screen.
- Choose the file type that best describes your data - Delimited or Fixed Width.
- Choose 65001: Unicode (UTF-8) from the drop-down list that appears next to File origin.
- Click on the Next button to display the Text Import Wizard - Step 2 or 3 window.
- Place a checkmark next to the delimiter that was used in the file you wish to import into Microsoft Excel 2007.  The Data preview window will show you how your data will appear based on the delimiter that you chose.
- Click on the Next button to display the Text Import Wizard - Step 3 of 3.
- Choose the appropriate data format for each column of data that you want to import.  You also have the option to not import one or more columns of data if you want.
- Click on the Finish button to finish importing your data into Microsoft Excel 2007.

Comment: I appreciate your response & tried this earlier too. It worked well, but I need a programming way to fix this. So, can't accept it.